# Pin Tool - intercepting an instruction by its address to dump the registers value

Tags: c, intel-pin

I'm trying to dump the register values at a given location in a binary. I know the correct address by reverse engineering, but I fail to use the API of Pin tool to indicate that *I would like to instrument that given instruction*.

Is there a way to call `INS_InsertCall(..)` on a given address, so I can dump the value of the registers from there ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do in your case is just to check for the instruction address (with [`INS_Address`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__GEN__IA32.html#ga6b685dec56c6a045f8cc3c03f52d054a)) and condition the `INS_INsertCall` with that in your instrumentation routine:

```
if(INS_Address(ins) == 0xdeadbeef) { // just check for your hard-coded address here.
     INS_InsertCall(...)
}
```

Amongst the other possibilities that come to my mind (but for something that simple I wouldn't try them):

- You could also use the [control regions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pintool-regions) with the [control manager](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/classCONTROLLER_1_1CONTROL__MANAGER.html).

  - See also the [IREGION controller](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/classCONTROLLER_1_1IREGION.html)
- The [filter RTN class](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/classINSTLIB_1_1FILTER__RTN.html) (you can get the RTN from your instruction).

**[edit]**

As for dumping the context, something like this (not tested or compiled, but you get the idea):

```
// in instrumentation
if(INS_Address(ins) == 0x1cafe /* whatever */) {
    INS_InsertPredicatedCall(ins, 
        IPOINT_BEFORE,       // decide if you want to point before or IPOINT_AFTER
        (AFUNPTR)AnalyzeContext,  // analysis routine
        IARG_INST_PTR,       // address of the ins
        IARG_CONST_CONTEXT,  // the const context (DO NOT MODIFY it in the analysis!)
        IARG_END);
}
```

See [IARG_CONST_CONTEXT](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/group__INST__ARGS.html#gga089c27ca15e9ff139dd3a3f8a6f8451dad3e65d643a63acb09d12b8538434ca45) in the documentation.

And the analysis routine:

```
VOID AnalyzeContext (ADDRINT ip, CONTEXT *ctxt){ 
    PIN_REGISTER reg_val; 
    PIN_GetContextRegval(ctxt, LEVEL_BASE::REG_RAX, reinterpret_cast<UINT8 *>(&reg_val));
    std::cout << std::hex << "REG_RAX: 0x" << reg_val << std::endl;
}
```

See [PIN_GetContextRegval](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/81205/Pin/html/group__CONTEXT__API.html#gab3ce54ce359ab95b0e5242543b802d67) for an overview of the API.